# Cannot get jQuery and RadioButtonList to Work

Tags: jquery, radiobuttonlist

I'm pulling my hair out trying to get a jQuery script working that will pick up the selected value in a RadioButtonList. I've done the usual thing when I can't get a script to run - cut and paste somebody else's into a blank page, get it working and then copy into the required page.

I have tried three different scripts, however, that take different approaches to defining the selected value but I can't get any of them to work, even though comments on some of the  webpages I got them from seem to suggest that they are working for other people.

This script throws an unrecognised expression error:

```
//In head with prior reference to local copy of jquery-1.4.1.js
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
            alert($("#RadioButtonList1").find("input[@checked]").val());
        });
    });
</script>

//In body
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
 <input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Submit" />
```

In the following code, the alert box justs gives 'undefined' (Note I've tried it with both the remote reference and reference to local copy of jquery-1.4.1.js )

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
  <title></title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
   </div>
   <input type="button" id="btnTest" value="Uncheck" />
  </form>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

 $('#btnTest').click(function () {
    alert($('#<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID %> input[type=radio]:checked').val());
 });

</script>

</html>
```

I've also tried the following in a basic HTML page (i.e. not asp.net) and it does nothing

```
//In head
$("input[@name='option_layout']").change(
function()
{
    if ($("input[@name='option_layout']:checked").val())
        $(".group").toggleClass("group_vert");
    else
        $(".group").toggleClass("group_vert");
    $(this).blur();
}
);

//In body
<input type="radio" name="option_layout" value="0" checked="checked" />
<input type="radio" name="option_layout" value="1" />
```

I've tried modifying .change to .click as I know that there is a bug in IE with .change, even though I had tested with no success in both IE and Fiefox. I also tried wrapping the code inside a   $(document).ready(function() block but no difference. I've also tried adding an alert box into the first line of the function but it again throws an unrecognised expression error.

Anyone any idea what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@` was deprecated/removed from [attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) in jQuery 1.3, so your first attept should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
    alert($("#RadioButtonList1 input[checked]").val());
  });
});
```

Or a bit more simplified using [the `:checked` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/):

```
$(function() {
  $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
    alert($("#RadioButtonList1 :checked").val());
  });
});
```

Also, [here's what I *think* you're after in the third attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/8nBGk/), just as a starting point :)

Comment: @mharran - You should comment if you're having issues...your question didn't involve a master page, I would have pointed out how to make this work if you asked :)

Comment: Sorry, Nick, I didn't realise that a master page could be causing problems as it's working fine with the rest of my jQuery code.

Also, I've found since that the solution I've just given doesn't work when I transfer the jQuery code into an external file - I'm still learning this stuff but I suspect that <%= ... %> doesn't work from an external file. 

For the moment, I'm using $("#MainContent_RadioButtonList1 ")... which is the name that the control gets in the output HTML. Any easy way around that?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Nick, your answer got me there ... eventually :)

Your first code

```
alert($("#RadioButtonList1 input[checked]").val());
```

wouldn't work at all, giving me 'undefined' in the alert box.

Your second code

```
alert($("#RadioButtonList1 :checked").val());
```

worked in a basic asp.net page but wouldn't work in a Master/Child page which is what I am using here. I changed it to

```
alert($("#<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID %>").find("input[checked]").val());
```

and it works fine.